# how using checkbox in stimulsoft

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

how change checked for checkbox in stimulsoft ?

```
Stimulsoft.Report.Components.StiCheckBox CheckBox1 = stiReport1.GetComponents()["CheckBox1"] as Stimulsoft.Report.Components.StiCheckBox;
            if (CheckBox1.CheckedValue == null || ((bool)CheckBox1.CheckedValue) == false)
            {
                CheckBox1.CheckedValue = true;

            }

 else CheckBox1.CheckedValue = false;
 Invalidate();
```

the check box does not work, the  cannot be checked. Need I set anything else other than "editable";
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can change the checkbox value in the report template.
If you need to change checkbox value in the rendered report you should do it other way.
Describe your problem more detailed to give you more accurate answer.